# When the site changed from Beer to Alcohol?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm going through the meta posts, but I can't find the relevant posts. Since when the site changed from Beer to Alcohol and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This change was made about a year ago.

The initial discussion happened here: [Should we broaden our scope?](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/q/118/37)

Once the decision was made, the follow up thread was here: [Shaken, not stirred; let's expand the site!](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/q/123/37)